# Run a project for debugging in Aptana (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, ide, github, pydev

I have imported a google app engine project from Github.  I believe that I need to add a debug configuration for it so that I can run it locally and debug it.

However, when I attempt to add the project as a debug configuration, it does not show up in dialog bow that I click to "browse" available projects even though it shows up in the pyDev package explorer.

Additionally, I have no idea why the "Git project" has an asterisk `(*)` to the left of its name and the word "master" in brackets to the right of it `[master]`.

I apologize that this is probably a novice question.  Unfortunately, I am not very knowledgeable in using IDEs, especially Aptana (Eclipse).

Below is a picture of what I think I need to do.  Thanks so much for viewing my question.  I really appreciate any help with this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your project as a python project:

right click project > python > set as pydev project -- or something like that :)

Then, you must properly configure your source folder in the project (see: http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html) -- this is the folder which should be added to the pythonpath for this project.

Also, make sure you go through the getting started guide: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html to properly configure PyDev.